# qt5 mainwindow for fileDialog is empty

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a simple FileDialog with Qt-Designer, but I am getting an empty page when I run it. I am running on a mac, and with python3.6. Can you tell me what I am missing in this code:

The UI has only the following features:

- a MainWindow
- a 'File' field in the top menu
- a 'Open' option within the 'File' field
- when the user clicks on the option and selects a file, the caller program prints the file name

Here are the commands that I have run:

```
pyuic5 bug1_ui.ui -o bug1_ui.py -x
   (or even: pyside2-uic bug1_ui.ui > bug1_ui.py)
python bug1_demo.py
```

What I am getting, when I run this program, is an empty window with the 'File' field missing:

[image]

I am attaching the codes for bug1_ui.ui (the UI xml saved from QT-designer), bug1_ui.py (generated by pyuic5), and bug1_demo.py (the calling program).

*bug1_ui.ui:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>524</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOpen"/>
    <addaction name="actionSave"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionOpen">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSave">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Save</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

*bug1_ui.py:*

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 524)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*bug1_demo.py:*

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction, QFileDialog
from bug1_ui import *
class MyForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.openFileDialog)
        self.show()
    def openFileDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/Users')
        if fname[0]:
            print('file={}'.format(fname[0]))
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: In MacOS the menubar is at the top of the screen, not the window, so I recommend you check the top of the screen when the window is in focus.

Comment: Oh, there it is! You saved my day again! Thanks much!